# Incorrect syntax near '=' in c# .net

Tags: c#, sql

i m trying to update data in database but it is showing an exception that is Incorrect syntax near '='.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("upgrade LoginForm set Password ='" + txtConPassword.Text + "' where UserName ='" + txtUser.Text + "' ", conn);
                var test = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (test == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password has been reset");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password did not reset");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed....." + ex.Message);

            }
```

Comment: Storing unhashed passwords and open to SQL injection. Nice.

Comment: This isn't really a C# question, is it?

Comment: Try debugging it and see what the cmd.CommandText contains before you run the query. Looks like it should work fine from what I can see, but that's a good step on the way to finding the issue at least. And yeah, there's no such SQL command as "Upgrade".

Comment: @AntP Don't you know `Upgrade` statement? It is a new statement that do auto _parameterized queries_, auto block _SQL Injection_ attacks and auto works like `Update` statement `:)`

Answer (score 4):

First change your `upgrade` to `update`. Second use parametrized queries.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update LoginForm set Password = @password where UserName = @user", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtConPassword.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUser.Text);
var test = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (test == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Password has been reset");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Password did not reset");
}
```

Parametrized queries secure you from SQL Injection attacks. Also variable types are resolved by framework (useful when passing `DateTime` variable to query).

Also please tag your questions more precisely because there are a lot of DBMS engines and sometimes it may be hard to guess what DBMS you are using.

Comment: ... and third, do not store store clear text passwords in the database, use [cryptographic hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 1):

In your sql query you are using upgrade please use update instead of upgrade

**Replace this:**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("upgrade LoginForm set Password ='" + txtConPassword.Text + "' where UserName ='" + txtUser.Text + "' ", conn);
```

**With following :**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update LoginForm set Password ='" + txtConPassword.Text + "' where UserName ='" + txtUser.Text + "' ", conn);
```

More over please don't assign your values directly into sql Parameter
query as it can lead to sql parameter Injection Attacks.

Comment: Your initial answer was "Replace {code block} with {code block}" without any explanation. That's a bad answer as it teaches nobody nothing. Maybe OP is helped, but that is not the point: copypasting never solved any problem. Explain what you changed and why. Then, your answer is badly formatted. Don't use blockquotes (`>`) if you're not quoting. Split code over multiple lines for readability. Don't Capitalize Random Words.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thank you sir , i modified my answer as per your suggestion and i follow the same for my future answers aswell Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UPGRADE should be UPDATE

Also, please look up SQL Parameterisation and password hashing before you release any code to production

Answer (score -2):

You can use the same code in another way as :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommadnText = "update LoginForm set Password ='" + txtConPassword.Text + "' where UserName ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
                var test = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (test == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password has been reset");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password did not reset");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed....." + ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
               if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
               {
                   conn.Close();
               }
            }
```

Comment: `upgrade LoginForm`... ?